# I am facing error with in passport and sequelize module

Tags: sequelize.js, where-clause, node-modules, mysql2, passport-local

**I am experiencing the following error**

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `nome`, `sobrenome`, `email`, `eAdmin`, `senha`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `administrador` AS `administrador` LIMIT 1;
Senha incorreta ~~~~


this is my code 

~~~~ const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const Admin = require("../models/Administrador");

module.exports = function (passport) {

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ 
    usernameField: 'email', 
    passwordField: 'senha', 
    passReqToCallback: true
  }, (req, email, senha, done) => {
    Admin.findOne({ where: { email: email } }).then((admin) => {
            
      if (!admin) {
        console.log("Conta não existe");
        return done(null, false, { mensagem: 'Essa conta não existe' });
      }
        
      bcrypt.compare(senha, admin.senha, (err, res) => {
        if (res) {
          console.log("Senha correta");
          return done(null, admin);
        } else {
          console.log("Senha incorreta " + err);
          return done(null, false, { mensagem: 'Senha incorreta ' + err });
        }
      });
    
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return done(err);
    });
  }));
    
  passport.serializeUser((admin, done) => {
    done(null, admin.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    Admin.findByPk(id).then((admin) => {
      done(null, admin);
    }).catch((err) => {
      done(err, null);
    });
  });

}; ~~~~
```

I was expecting a login authentication to be done that would redirect my admin to the administrative area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UR31.png)

I've set everything up but always end up falling into the same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yGFW.png)